# EC2 Linux AMI default directory permission for new files

Tags: linux, permissions, amazon-ec2, file-permissions

I'm having issues applying a default permission for new files and directories on my EC2 Linux instance.

I'm trying to have all my new files and directories in my wordpress directory associated with `ftpaccess` group and have 775 permissions. 
For some reason I'm only getting 644 permissions for new files.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are the files being created?

Comment: Setting the permission of the directory to 775 will not automatically set the permissions of files within the directory to similar permissions. You will have to configure a default umask, or set the permissions manually each time you upload files.

Comment: I made a default umask of 0022. Still not working. Is that incorrect?

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

yes 664 is the correct file permission for the new files being created. But it will be for files created on that instance, in case of ftp make sure the appropriate file changes are done and checked when the file is sent.

Comment: What changes do I need to do in case of ftp?